# CSS3 animation works in Chrome not Firefox

Tags: css, css-animations

I am having trouble figuring out why this works in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

My code:

```css
#header3{
    background: url(/images/mynecraft/clouds3.png) repeat-x center 20px;
    -webkit-animation-name:cloud-crawl-header3;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 120s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -moz-animation-name:cloud-crawl-header3;
    -moz-animation-duration:120s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function:linear;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes cloud-crawl-header3{
        from{background-position: -100% 20px, center top}to{background-position: 100% 20px, center top}
}
@-moz-keyframes cloud-crawl-header3{
        from{background-position: -100% 20px, center top}to{background-position: 100% 20px, center top}
}
```

What's the problem with it?

Comment: Why not just use [-prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have two sets of positions of `background-position` like this: `-100% 20px, center top`?

I think it should be:

```
@-webkit-keyframes cloud-crawl-header3 {
    from {
        background-position: -100% 20px;
    }
    to { 
        background-position: 100% 20px;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes cloud-crawl-header3 {
    from {
        background-position: -100% 20px;
    }
    to { 
        background-position: 100% 20px;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a -moz- prefix, and a -webkit- prefix. There is no -moz-webkit-.

Comment: You can't say it didn't get your attention :) After the edit, it becomes a +1.